# how smart contract know a real owner of account has requested the withdraw method?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, validation

I need to know when I receive the request on Withdraw method, how does smart contract know that the real owner of the account has sent the request?

is this done automatically by the system before calling the method? basically any one has access to the public key of accounts. does smart contract do more things behind the scene?

Comment: I think this question needs more details. For ex., withdraw from where? Also I'm not sure where's the problem: if a transaction has the correct signature it means it was sent by the real owner (of the private key). It doesn't matter the smart contract.

Comment: @0xSanson  i mean a user has called a method. and on the parameters has sent the receiver address. and from msg.sender, I can get the address of the sender. the problem is that is msg.sender trusted by default?

Comment: Yes, msg.sender is always the true caller of the contract

Comment: msg.sender its not always the true caller, they call could have been maid from another contract when the transac tion origin came from an EOA, try looking into tx.origin